# How to refer to a specific version of Adobe Connect API Version?

Tags: web-services, api, version, refer, adobe-connect

I found the following documentation for Adobe Connect web service API 8

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/8.0/webservices/connect_8_webservices.pdf

The following link, lists the changes in API 9

https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/webservices/whats-new-connect-9-web.html

And following is the sample usage of API

$host/api/xml?action=principal-list&session=apac1breezra3ssd5h2mgth2mod5h2p22th2mgo

In the above API call we are not referring to any specific version of API. So how do I refer to a specific version of API(say 9.5) so that my application will not stop working suddenly when the web service or API is upgraded.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version mentioned in the API docs is the Adobe Connect Server version which the API is used. Therefore there is no option to select an API version.

So to decide which API version you need to use, you should know which server version you are running.

You can get your server version with the following command.

$host/version.txt

This an example output of the above URL (package value is the version one need to check):

```
package=9.2.1.116.20140226.1245860
installer=9.2.1.109.20140225.1248099
fmg=9.2.1.0.95.20140225.1235801
fms=9.2.1.0.95.20140225.1235801
presenter=9.1.1.3.20130627.1194934
cps=9.2.1.95.20140225.1248427
mssql=9.2.1.0.95.20140225.12358013
teleintercall=9.2.1.2.20131219.1235801
telearkadin=9.2.1.2.20131219.1235801
telepremierena=9.2.1.1.20131219.1235801
telepremiereemea=9.2.1.1.20131219.1235801
cpshelp=9.2.1.6.20140207.1244451
addins=9.2.1.0.105.20140226.1235801
dbscripts=9.2.1.5.20140212.1239652
teleavaya=9.2.1.2.20131219.1235801
telecisco=9.2.1.2.20131219.1235801
telemeetingone=9.2.1.2.20131219.1235801
telephonyservice=9.2.1.2.20140111.1238365
CQ-Events-App=9.2.1.6.20140225.1238847
CQServer=cq-quickstart-5.5.0-20120220.jar
tomcat=7.0.40.0
tomcat64=7.0.40.0
source_fmg=2.0.1.19_8x8
source_fms=4_0_3_4065
```

Comment: You can alternatively get connect version with $host/api/xml?action=common-info and read <version> node and communicate with server. I assume you are developing an app to be able to work with multiple versions.

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot.